# UIView contains NSTimer - not releasing

Tags: objective-c, uiview, nstimer, cadisplaylink

I'm using one UIView subclass that has some CAAnimation which would be performed after performsegue from another class. In the UIView class, I'm using CADisplayLink and NSTimer to increment the CATextLayer used in the animation. Whenever, I came back to the previous view controller after running the animation, it keeps on running in the background. When I go to View controller where the animation is playing, it shows me incorrect count. Is there anything wrong with my code ?

In the .h file,

```
@property (assign,nonatomic) CFTimeInterval duration;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *tim1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *tim2;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *tim3;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *startup;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *starter;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *suspender;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *humansum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *transportsum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *wastesum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *watersum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *energysum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *humanslowsum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *transportslowsum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *wasteslowsum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *waterslowsum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *energyslowsum;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CADisplayLink  *displayLink;
```

In the .m file, 
//Below code is called inside a method

```
displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(tick:)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- (void)tick:(CADisplayLink *)sender
{
    duration = sender.duration;
 startup=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(2+(0.05*duration)) target:self selector:@selector(calltheanimating_function) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

 if(initil==YES){
        //
            humansum  =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(15.4+(0.05*duration)) target:self selector:@selector(sum1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    else{
        humansum  =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:13.4 target:self selector:@selector(sum1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
```

In the sum1 method,

```
-(void)sum1{
    NSLog(@"Hvalue %f",humanvalue);
    num11=humanvalue;//
    CATextLayer *humanscore=self.layers[@"humanscore"];
    humanscore.string=@"0";
    actualtext=0;
    tmep=0;
        humanslowsum =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.7/(0.7*num11)) target:self selector:@selector(final1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

For implementing ease out function, I'm using 75% of the increment as fast and 25% increment as slow which is mentioned in the requirement.

```
-(void)final1{
    if(tmep<round(num11)){
        tmep++;
        CATextLayer *t=self.layers[@"stepscore"];
        int m=[t.string intValue];
        m++;
        t.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",m];
        CATextLayer *humanscore=self.layers[@"humanscore"];
        actualtext++;
        humanscore.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",actualtext];
        NSLog(@"%d",m);
    }
    else{
        [humanslowsum  invalidate];
    }
}
```

This timer keeps running even though if I invalidate the timer, remove the view from the superview inside dealloc() method. Please help me with the issue.

Comment: Are you sure dealloc is called? It has a retain cycle since the view is retaining the timer and the timer retains the view.

Comment: Yes, I'm invalidating all the timers inside dealloc and I've checked the debugging mode and the method gets called

Comment: Can you also print the values of humanslowsum? It seems it is getting replaced but the previous value is not invalidated. This might be creating multiple timers for that variable.

Comment: I'm getting the values which is stopped in the middle and if I go back to the previous view, then it keeps incrementing and printing in the console. I don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found an answer by simple method. Creating an IBOutlet of the uiview subview inside super view and invalidating the NSTimer(s) over there while performing segue.